# Python (scipy) import time from text file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text, scipy

I have the text file:

```
2010-05-16
2010-09-26
2011-04-28
```

Each line is a string: `YYYY-MM-dd`

My goal is to read this text file and to write this information to array.

```
import scipy as sp
x=sp.empty(200,ftype=sp.datetime64)     
file=open(place,'r')
for p in file:
    x[i]=p
```

But it does not work. I see "an error". How can I solve this task? I know that I can use Panda but I need to write this to scipy array.

Comment: Please tell us what the error says and what line(s) cause it.

Comment: ValueError: Cannot create a NumPy datetime other than NaT with generic untis. This error is to line x[i]=p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np


x = np.empty(200, dtype='datetime64[D]')

with open(place, 'r') as f:
    for i, date in enumerate(f):
        x[i] = date.strip()
```

Firstly, it's a `dtype`, not an `ftype`. Then, we need to use `datetime64[D]` since this is just a date, not a date and time. Then, `date` has a newline at the end, which results in a parse error (`strip()` fixes this). You might also want to use `np.zeros()` instead of `np.empty()`.

You can access these methods through SciPy as well, but they're technically a part of NumPy, so just use `import numpy as np`.

Comment: Perfect, no problem, glad to help! :) If this solves your problem, please click the checkbox by the voting arrows next to the question to mark the question as answered.